# FullCalendar: Jump to first event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

The default view for my FullCalendar setup is agendaWeek.  I want to set it so that when the calendar loads, it doesn't start on the current date.  I'd like to to automatically jump to the first week containing events.  Is that possible?  I've gone through the docs and if it is, I sure haven't seen how. :)  Thanks!

Comment: you would need to evaluate the events array and find the first date and set the view accordingly. Or make an api call to get that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `defaultDate` to the first event in your calendar? [Docs from fullcalendar.io here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you, that's exactly what I needed.